# TCP communication between Android Client and Universal Windows Platform

Tags: c#, android, tcp, uwp, raspberry-pi2

I'm trying to create a TCP client on Android and a UWP server. Server should run on a Raspberry PI 2.

Client works with a synchronous server, but it doesn't work with this asynchronous server.

This is the Client

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    TextView textResponse;
    EditText editTextAddress, editTextPort;
    Button buttonConnect, buttonClear;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editTextAddress = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.address); //
        editTextPort = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.port);
        buttonConnect = (Button)findViewById(R.id.connect);
        buttonClear = (Button)findViewById(R.id.clear);
        textResponse = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.response);

        buttonConnect.setOnClickListener(buttonConnectOnClickListener);

        buttonClear.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                textResponse.setText("");
            }});
    }


    OnClickListener buttonConnectOnClickListener =
            new OnClickListener(){
                String tMsg = "TEST";

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    MyClientTask myClientTask = new MyClientTask(
                            editTextAddress.getText().toString(),
                            Integer.parseInt(editTextPort.getText().toString()), tMsg);
                    myClientTask.execute();
                }};

    public class MyClientTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        String dstAddress;
        int dstPort;
        String response = "";
        String msgToServer;

        MyClientTask(String addr, int port, String msgTo){
            dstAddress = addr;
            dstPort = port;
            msgToServer = msgTo;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

            Socket socket = null;
            DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;

            try {
                socket = new Socket(dstAddress, dstPort);
                dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

                if(msgToServer != null){
                    dataOutputStream.writeBytes(msgToServer);
                }
                ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream =
                        new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

                int bytesRead;
                InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();

    /*
     * notice:
     * inputStream.read() will block if no data return
     */
                while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1){
                    byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    response += byteArrayOutputStream.toString("UTF-8");
                }

            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                response = "UnknownHostException: " + e.toString();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                response = "IOException: " + e.toString();
            }finally{
                if(socket != null){
                    try {
                        socket.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            textResponse.setText(response);
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

    }

}
```

And this is the Server

```
private async void AvviaServer()
        {
            try
            {
                //Create a StreamSocketListener to start listening for TCP connections.
                Windows.Networking.Sockets.StreamSocketListener socketListener = new Windows.Networking.Sockets.StreamSocketListener();

                //Hook up an event handler to call when connections are received.
                socketListener.ConnectionReceived += SocketListener_ConnectionReceived;

                //Start listening for incoming TCP connections on the specified port. You can specify any port that's not currently in use.
                await socketListener.BindServiceNameAsync("9999");

                //TxtMex.Text = "PRONTO";
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                TxtMex.Text = e.Message;
            }
        }

        private async void SocketListener_ConnectionReceived(Windows.Networking.Sockets.StreamSocketListener sender, Windows.Networking.Sockets.StreamSocketListenerConnectionReceivedEventArgs args)
        {



            //Read line from the remote client.
            Stream inStream = args.Socket.InputStream.AsStreamForRead();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(inStream);
            request = await reader.ReadLineAsync();

            //Send the line back to the remote client.
            Stream outStream = args.Socket.OutputStream.AsStreamForWrite();
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(outStream);
            await writer.WriteLineAsync(request);
            await writer.FlushAsync();
        }
```

Thanks everybody

Comment: So how does it not work, do you get an exception or something?

Comment: It looks like the server doesn't receive anything, infact the client receive no answers.

Comment: But is there a connection? You run Windosw 10 on the raspi? UWP? What did i miss?

Comment: `Server should run on a Raspberry PI `. ??? So it does not? What are you trying to say?

Comment: |`socketListener.ConnectionReceived += SocketListener_ConnectionReceived`. The `+=` looks a typo.

Comment: You implemented a connection received handler. But not a message received handler for the server.

Answer (score 1):

We cannot see what your client writes. But your server is expecting a line. It looks as if your client is not sending a line. Add a "\n" or "\r\n" to the message string to send a line.